# React-Redux eCommerce app: storing data in Redux state vs calling API

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, e-commerce

I am new to React and Redux, and currently I am building a very simple eCommerce app for practice.  This app is retrieving its data from https://fakestoreapi.com/docs .  I am a little confused about the best way to go about organizing what to call from my Redux state vs from the API...

Should I be calling the API once upon App.js render to fetch all products, and then storing the fetched products (along with all their data like descr, price, image etc) in my Redux state?  Then when viewing the Product List page, or a Single Product page, I would pull the data directly from the Redux state?

Or, should I not be storing any product data in Redux state, and instead be calling the API each time I render the Product List page and a Single Product page?

Also, regarding the Cart state, for each item in the cart, should I be storing all the details (i.e. title, descr, price, image etc) in the Redux state?  Then when rendering the Cart page, I would just be pulling those details from Redux?

Or, should I be just storing the product IDs and quantities in my Redux state?  Then when viewing the Cart page, I would fetch the product details from the API for each item in the Cart?

In my mind, I can see pros and cons for both approaches, but I was wondering if there are some best practices, or recommendations on what should be considered when trying to choose the ideal approach?

Answer (score 1):

It can be bit confusing but You have to change the way you look at your Global State.

For State : We can store User's Data, his actions, theme settings and others in State. As these are user information which we don't want to fetch multiple time during his session.

You can also store response from API into State. So that you can better handle it and If you think data is not going to change for that certain user. then you Use your Global State instead of making an API Call.

If Your actions makes data change than do an API Call.

In Case of Cart. You should Store that data in your state. As you wouldn't want to make multiple request to your API. Saving that data in State would be helpful in better UX, and will save cost of lots of API Calls

Answer (score 0):

So from my understanding

Storing the data from the API in the redux store at the time of server.js getting  rendering first time is a good way . Because if you want to use the same data in other component it will be easy to have a global store where you can get the data multiple item by one time render.